# Can I permanently kill important people?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Morrowind, it was possible to permanently kill NPCs who were involved in the main story.  This would result in a message basically informing you that you had broken the world and to reload a save if you want to make progress.  In Oblivion, this was changed so that important NPCs were "knocked out" instead of killed.

In Skyrim, is there any (outside of console or game file editing) way to permanently kill an important NPC or can I go on a killing spree *relatively* care free?

Comment: It's been confirmed that shopkeepers and such will stay dead - not sure about key characters. Back up your save and have a go ;)

Comment: Another great question title.

Comment: YOU HAVE BROKEN THE INTERNET. Please restore a backup to continue.

Comment: I was just about to roll the title back before OrigamiRobot did, but see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/821 for some prior discussion on the subject.

Comment: You can go on a killing spree, however your "karma" will make passing through certain areas a pain, since guards will essentially chase you before you even know which side you're on.

Comment: I miss the days of Morrowind when you could kill and essential NPC and have a message saying your world is doomed.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Important NPCs are invulnerable, like Oblivion.

You might close off some smaller sidequests, but the folks necessary for the main story (for instance) have a tendency to be "incapacitated" from "killing" blows.

So feel free to go nuts.

Interestingly, NPC allies behave a little different, even if they are non-essential (and thus ripe for killing). When they get reduced to below 0 health, they revert into the "yield " state, which usually means enemy NPCs stop focusing on them to come after you instead. If they get hit while in this state, they will die.

Additionally, **you** cannot put them into this state - your attacks will directly kill them.

Comment: You heard it here folks, the Gaming.SE mods support mass murder.

Comment: Must have been a combo then, as my follower, Lydia, got pwned by some orcs and seemed pretty dead. Even kicking her didn't wake her up.

Comment: I was assaulted by thugs as I was leaving a dungeon and fled to a high spot to use my bow. I was distracted by a circling dragon and when I looked back my follower (Lydia also) seemed to be dead and the thugs were right on top of me. I would have died at the last second but it seems Lydia regained consciousness, looted a staff off one of the dead thugs and started shooting lightning bolts up the mountain to my aid! Epic.

Comment: @deizel Ah, so Lydia can be useful if: you leave a dungeon with some orcs thugs outside, a dragon is circling the area, she dies, you kill one of the orcs thugs that happens to have a staff on him AND you almost die. Good to know.

Answer (score 34):

You can't permanently kill important people, they only become temporarily incapacitated when badly hurt. I just confirmed it on the XBox 360.

I was walking along with an important NPC and we attacked a Giant. The Giant practically one-shotted him and kneeled down in agony while recovering.

So while they aren't blown unconscious into a ragdoll like in Oblivion, they are incapacitated while they recover.

The recovery takes around 10 to 15 seconds, so if you're relying on his power (like I was...) his demise into recovery mode really hurts you as the monsters stop aggroing him and focus on you instead.

Comment: Do note what Raven Dreamer said: **you** (the player) can permanently kill important people yourself.

Comment: @Konerak: No you can't. Important NPCs do not die, they are just incapacitated. Rolled back to my previous answer.

Comment: @Konerak Read Raven Dreamer's whole answer. He's talking about non-essential allies.

Comment: There's "Protected", people only you can kill, and "essential", which nobody can kill without mods.