# Can spontaneously killing no-name hunters hurt my game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can I just kill hunters if I want to? I hate them, because it was a hunter that set bounty on me, because I stole from her. The guys that came for me were super-strong and I was a very low level, I was lucky I beat them.

Can I kill any hunter I see? Is there any downside to it? (except selling stuff)

Comment: Oh, so it's HER fault that you stole from her.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Exactly. She's been hunting and fishing in these parts for years.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I was alone, hungry and scared. level1!

Comment: @IAdapter Yeah, that last bit - about you being level 1 - is exactly why you *shouldn't* have messed with her. Duh.

Answer (score 11):

Skyrim lets you kill most people. **The worst that can happen** as a result of your (mis)deeds is preventing yourself from starting / finishing a particular quest or misc. objective.

If the character does not have an actual name, i.e., Hunter, Bandit, or Markarth Guard, they are totally killable (and in fact, tend to respawn after a few days) with no real consequences (other than potential bounty / murder related issues involved with killing them in the first place).

See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/34880/336) for more info about killing important people.

Comment: Also note that you *can* kill some merchants, and [not all merchants have successors](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45669/do-all-merchants-have-replacements) who will run the store for them.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you are careful to avoid the bounty I'd guess you should be OK. Also: there may be others settings bounty hunters on you, be wary of those if you are low level.

Comment: I'm not mid-level, so I can beat almost anybody :) I will show those hunters!

Comment: Almost gave this a -1 for not mentioning the potential of killing quest-givers, but then realized the question was more specific than its title. Fixed title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can kill them you just have to be very careful because if other important/ main character or "guest givers" are there then you will get a bounty, but other times murders are sent after you along with really high leveled bounty hunters.